# Discord.js ComponentType is not defined while trying to use a component collector

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a discord bot that allows users to vote on teams by clicking on a button with the teams icon. I am trying to follow this guide to set up a component collector for those buttons: https://discordjs.guide/message-components/interactions.html#awaiting-components

However on this line:

```
const collector = message2.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: ComponentType.StringSelect, time: 3_600_000 });
```

I get the following error: `ReferenceError: ComponentType is not defined`

Here is the entire slash command file so you can get the full picture:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ActionRowBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { teamList } = require('../teamList');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('../config.json');



// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions] });
client.login(token);

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('newaddgame')
        .setDescription('Sets up a game for placing bets.')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('team1')
                .setDescription('Team 1')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices(
                    { name: 'Bilibili Gaming', value: 'Bilibili Gaming'},
                    { name: 'JDG Gaming', value: 'JDG Gaming'},
                    { name: 'Gen.G', value: 'Gen.G'},
                    { name: 'T1', value: 'T1'},
                    { name: 'Cloud9', value: 'Cloud9'},
                    { name: 'Golden Guardians', value: 'Golden Guardians'},
                    { name: 'G2 Esports', value: 'G2 Esports'},
                ))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('team2')
                .setDescription('Team 2')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices(
                    { name: 'Bilibili Gaming', value: 'Bilibili Gaming'},
                    { name: 'JDG Gaming', value: 'JDG Gaming'},
                    { name: 'Gen.G', value: 'Gen.G'},
                    { name: 'T1', value: 'T1'},
                    { name: 'Cloud9', value: 'Cloud9'},
                    { name: 'Golden Guardians', value: 'Golden Guardians'},
                    { name: 'G2 Esports', value: 'G2 Esports'},
                )),
    async execute(interaction) {
        // Set up team information
        const team1 = interaction.options.getString('team1');
        const team2 = interaction.options.getString('team2');
        const teamArray = [team1, team2];
        let teamMessage1 = '';
        let teamMessage2 = '';
        const team1Info = teamList.find(team => team.name === teamArray[0]);
        const team2Info = teamList.find(team => team.name === teamArray[1]);
        teamMessage1 = team1Info.emoji + ' ' + team1Info.name;
        teamMessage2 = team2Info.name + ' ' + team2Info.emoji;

        // Build buttons
        const team1Button = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('team1Button')
            // .setLabel(team1Info.name)
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            .setEmoji(team1Info.emoji);

        const team2Button = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('team2Button')
            // .setLabel(team2Info.name)
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            .setEmoji(team2Info.emoji);

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(team1Button, team2Button);

        // Send the message and add buttons
        await interaction.reply({content: 'Game posted.', fetchReply: true});
        const message2 = await client.channels.cache.get('1077612967639666738').send({
            content: teamMessage1 + ' vs ' + teamMessage2,
            components: [row],
        });

        const collector = message2.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: ComponentType.StringSelect, time: 3_600_000 });

        collector.on('collect', async i => {
            const selection = i.values[0];
            await i.reply(`${i.user} has selected ${selection}!`);
        });
    },
};
```

How can I resolve that error?

EDIT:
I tried adding importing `ComponentType` form discord.js:
`const { SlashCommandBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ActionRowBuilder, ComponentType } = require('discord.js');`

But now I am getting this error:

```
D:\Projects\iTeroLolApp\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:50
        if (channel && !channel.isTextBased()) return;
                                ^

TypeError: channel.isTextBased is not a function
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (D:\Projects\iTeroLolApp\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:50:33)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (D:\Projects\iTeroLolApp\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\Projects\iTeroLolApp\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\Projects\iTeroLolApp\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:489:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\Projects\iTeroLolApp\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10)
    at callListener (D:\Projects\iTeroLolApp\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\Projects\iTeroLolApp\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:209:9)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (D:\Projects\iTeroLolApp\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1180:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:514:28)

Node.js v18.17.0
```

Still seeking an answer here.

Comment: Import `ComponentType` form discord.js, just like you did with others.

Comment: What's your discord.js version? Sounds like you just need to upgrade it.

Comment: You can't change a question once it's been solved. If you have a new issue, make a new post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remember that this bug occurs when the version of discord.js is older. Simply follow these steps to update:

```bash
npm remove discord.js
npm i discord.js
```

---

Old answer:

just import `ComponentType` enum.

```
- const { SlashCommandBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ActionRowBuilder } = require('discord.js');
+ const { SlashCommandBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ActionRowBuilder, ComponentType } = require('discord.js');
```

Comment: I updated my question to reflect these changes and the error that ensued. Thank you very much for attempting to fix my problem. Sorry someone downvoted you.

Comment: The old answer is the correct answer